# How to wrap texts including inline elements with “p” tag in Plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some texts that’s needed to be wrapped by “p” tag. How do I achieve this by Plain JavaScript? I tried with the below script but it omits the inline elements.

```
var texts = function (first, firstTexts) {
    first = first.firstChild;
    while(first) {
        if (first.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            firstTexts.push(first);
        first = first.nextSibling;
    }
};

var textWrap = function (thisText) {
    for(var node of thisText) {
        var addTag = document.createElement('p');
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(addTag, node);
        addTag.appendChild(node);
    }
};

var textElements = [];
texts(document.querySelector(".div"), textElements);
textWrap(textElements);
```

jQuery solutions are available. But plain JavaScript answer could be elegant. I searched Stack Overflow so many times and other sites too but I didn't find a clue.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="div">
<a href="#read">Learning</a> is <i>growing</i> process. 
<br>
Knowledge <span>removes the fear</span>. 
</div>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="div">
<p><a href="#read">Learning</a> is <i>growing</i> process.</p>
<br>
<p>Knowledge <span>removes the fear</span>.</p>
</div>
```

I am a beginner of learning JavaScript. Friends please help me to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id="myDiv"` in `<div...>`, then:

```
var innerHTML=document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<p>"+innerHTML.split("<br>").join("</p>\n<br>\n<p>")+"</p>";
```

One-time solution...  It will keep adding `<p>` - `</p>`s...

Comment: .split() and .join(). Excellent presence of mind. Nice and very simple answer. Thank you, sir.